# Is there any way to simulate something similar Nintendo's Streepass functionality in iOS?

Tags: ios

Essentially is there any way to have an app run at all times in the background and sense other iOS devices around it running the same app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can have an app monitor your current location in the background. When you get location updates, you could talk to a web server that would tell you if other people are nearby.

You can't make apps that run as services on iOS though. There are only a handful of things they're allowed to do in the background like monitor location and play music.